# Proof check: proving a neighborhood is an open set?

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that a neighborhood is an open set by picking an arbitrary point in it and showing it's an interior point. On my final exam I couldn't think of a way to use the triangle inequality(which I think is the right way) so here's what I wrote:

Let Nr(x) be a neighborhood about a point x. Then Nr(x)={y:d(x,y) < r } . So for y in Nr(x), we can find the distance between y and the bound r and divide it by 2 to get a new radius that is completely contained in Nr(x). So y is an interior point which implies Nr(x) is open.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Your question looks like it was chopped off at the end.  (Sorry, I looked at the question as you were writing it.)  Please make sure when you save a question that it is finished.

Answer (score 0):

The distance you want is not between $y$ and $r$, it is between $d(x,y)$ and $r$. And I think your proof is only valid in one dimension.

Assuming you are working in a topology that obeys the triangle inequality, you can use that to extend your proof to multiple dimensions. If this is what your professor was looking for, I'm afraid the answer you provided should get very little partial credit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are working in a metric space with the metric $d$? If you know the space you are working in, that could change this proof. For now, I will just assume your space is some $X$. Additionally, neighborhoods need not be open, depending on the definition you are using. However, if you are defining a neighborhood of radius $r$ about the point $x \in X$ to be $$N_r(x) = \{y:d(x,y)<r \}$$ then these sets will always be open in your metric space. That remains to be proven. Currently, it seems you are trying to prove $N_r(x)$ is open by showing that you can squeeze another open set inside of $N_r(x)$ about $x$. My problem with that is the open set you are squeezing inside of $N_r(x)$ is itself a neighborhood of the form $N_p(x)$, which is to say you are assuming that neighborhoods are open to prove that neighborhoods are open; that will not work. I would not buy your proof that $x$ is an interior point of $N_r(x)$.